# How to create canvas element inside div element dynamically using html angularjs?

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, canvas

I would like to know that how can I create canvas tag inside the  element dynamically, actually I'm uploading json file(giving my image urls) to display the 3D/2D images on my html page, but I'm not able to display my images, if canvas tag with some height and distance would be there, then the images are showing properly. I'm getting all the div id's, I need only those canvas setting inside div. Please let me know that how to do this ? Thanks in advance.

json: `[{"name":"imageurl","value":"/images/Image1.nii"},{"name":"3d","value":"3d0"},{"name":"sliceX","value":"sliceX0"},{"name":"sliceY","value":"sliceY0"},{"name":"sliceZ","value":"sliceZ0"}, {"name":"imageurl","value":"/images/Image2.nii"}, {"name":"3d","value":"3d1"},{"name":"sliceX","value":"sliceX1"},{"name":"sliceY","value":"sliceY1"},{"name":"sliceZ","value":"sliceZ1"}]`

desired html would be:
on first time:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in vals" data-imgsrc="/images/Image1.nii">
    <div id="3d0"><canvas height="150" width="130"></div>
    <div id="sliceX0"><canvas height="160" width="135"></div>
    <div id="sliceY0"><canvas height="150" width="130"></div>
    <div id="sliceZ0"><canvas height="160" width="135"></div>
    </div>
```

on second time:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vals" data-imgsrc="/images/Image2.nii">
<div id="3d1"><canvas height="150" width="130"></div>
<div id="sliceX1"><canvas height="150" width="130"></div>
<div id="sliceY1"><canvas height="160" width="135"></div>
<div id="sliceZ1"><canvas height="160" width="135"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: run canvas rendering code inside `$scope.$applyAsync(function(){ ... })`

Comment: Hi YOU, thanks for your reply, may i know how can i apply this function for my code:  $scope.loadFile = function(){ ------ }. Thanks.

Comment: how so sure how your app render canvas, but wrap the codes that render canvas inside $applyAsync should render it properly theoratically.